# How to retrieve a specific data from database in ASP and put that data in a variable

Tags: mysql, vba, asp-classic

Problem: I have a database called `admin` which has `id`, `username` and `password` column. Now I need to put this `id` in a variable called `Dim ID` for a specific username.

If I run this query:

```
adoRS.Source = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username= '"& username &"' AND password ='"& password &"' "
```

I will get a particular row in the database and a particular `id`. So, the problem is how to retrieve that `id` from the above query and put it in the declared variable called `ID`

One particular solution would be using a `while` loop as shown below:

```
 do
  col1 = adoRS.Fields("id")
  id = col1
  adoRS.MoveNext
Loop While Not adoRS.EOF
```

Since we just have one piece of data in the `col1` variable, it would be much nicer if we could skip the `do while` process. So the question is how you retrieve the data and put that data in the `id` variable without using a `while` loop statement.

Answer (score 1):

When using an ADO recordset, if you just want the value, you can just grab the value.

```
ID = adoRS.Fields("ID").Value
```

If the admin table is going to have more than one row with the same userName and Password, you probably have problems elsewhere, but will want to either send whatever you're doing with ID off to a method, or load up all of the ID's into an array.

If there are more than a handful, the getRows method may be useful as well.

(And, really, you shouldn't do a SELECT * if you just want ID.  SELECT ID FROM Admin should work just fine.  And sanitize USER and PASSWORD when you build that SQL string.  Consider using a command object.  And don't store the password, store a hash of the password.  And eat your vegetables.)

Comment: what do you mean my hash of the password.. how to do it. ??

Comment: It works... the above example... i need to get some readings for the ADO connection .. this is awsome.. anyway.. thank you .. and again what do you mean by hash of password and how to do it ..

Comment: Ideally you should hash **and** salt your passwords: http://dustwell.com/how-to-handle-passwords-bcrypt.html